# Package for naming conventions

Tags: pdftex, packages

I'm looking package for generating naming convention documents. Something like this:
https://www.micron.com/~/media/documents/products/part-numbering-guide/numdram.pdf

Is there any ready to use package or I should do this manually?

Edit:
To make things more clear I'm looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{<unknown>}

\begin{document}
\<somecommand>{K}{1}{Description 1}
\<somecommand>{9}{2}{Description 2}
\<somecommand>{X}{X}{Description 3}
\end{document}
```

I expect some output like this:
[image: Code Information]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please specify what exactly you need and add a minimal code example (MWE)?

Comment: @TeXnician I want to do the same as in the pdf:
ABCDEF.....

A - something
B - something
etc....

Comment: In general you should give a short summary here and specify what exactly you need. You should combine this with a minimal code example (MWE).

Comment: @StefanMavrodiev: What you highlight in the image looks completely different from the other document link you specify. It's also not clear how the latest code addition relates to the image. For example, I assume that you would have to specify `\somecommand{.}{#}{description}` for all possible numbers `#` in your sequence? Can you be more specific in terms of the input and expected output? Specifics do help narrow down the things you want or are struggling with.

Comment: @Werner I'm not looking for code snippet. I'm just asking if there is ready package that is capable of generating code information like the image (or in the pdf). I know the two example doesn't look the same, but the principle is the same. Have some code, and specify description for each character. If there is no such package, I'm going to use tikz for the job.

Comment: Have you searched around [CTAN](https://ctan.org)? I looked a little bit, without finding anything, but I may not have looked in the right place.